# Redirect page using HTACCESS to URL that contains question mark in it?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

here's my question:

I want  to redirect all requests for

```
http://mypage.com/archives/17080
TO
http://mypage.com/p?-17080
```

OR

```
http://mypage.com/archives/85436
TO
http://mypage.com/p?-85436
```

Im using this rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^archives/([-A-z0-9]+)/?$ p?-$1
```

But it doesnt seems to work...
Also when i remove the question mark from the redirect to url:

```
RewriteRule ^archives/([-A-z0-9]+)/?$ p-$1
```

everything is working fine. So my guess is that the **?** is causing this problem.
Any kind of help will be well appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your  regex is wrong. Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^archives/([A-Z0-9]+)/?$ /p?-$1 [L,QSA,NC,NE]
```

You have in your regex this character range `[A-z]` which includes many other characters outside `[A-Za-z]` range.

Comment: Try to provide as much details as possible. What didn't work and what error you got? Do you have other rules as will there?

Comment: HI, its simply redirecting to the "http://mypage.com/p", so the question mark is still a problem

Comment: In your browser you will see `http://mypage.com/p` but it will `-$1` in query string. If you want URL to change in browser also then use: `RewriteRule ^archives/([A-Z0-9]+)/?$ /p?-$1 [L,QSA,NC,NE,R]`